# Segmentation Fault in vsprintf()

Tags: c++, static, stack, printf

```
    #define printm(p) writeToAnalyticsFile p
    void writeToAnalyticsFile (const char* format, ...)
    {
        std::string errorLog;
        std::string headerLine = "\"errorText\":";
        FILE *fp = fopen( "Analyse.txt", "w" );
        if( 0 == fp )
        {

        }
        else
        {
            va_list args;
            va_start (args, format);
            vsprintf (const_cast<char*>(errorLog.c_str()),format, args);
            va_end (args);
            fputs(headerLine.c_str(),fp);
            fputs("\"",fp);
            fputs( errorLog.c_str(), fp );
            fputs("\"",fp);

            fclose(fp);
        }
    }


    class abc
    {

    public:
        static const char *  func()
        {
            std::string str = "john";
            return str.c_str();
        }
    };


    int main()
    {

        printm(("My  Name is %s and surname is %s and age is %d",abc::func(),"john",25));
        return 0;
    }
```

I basically want to replace printm((--- )) with writeToAnalytics(--) which writes data to file.

I am getting Segmentation Fault with below code.
Problem is with calling abc::func() in main. Is it because of local storage of str in func()?

Comment: Yes, just `return "john"` if you want a statically allocated const char*.

Answer (score 2):

The `func` function is incorrect, as it is returning an invalid pointer:

```
    static const char *  func()
    {
        std::string str = "john";
        return str.c_str();
    }
```

The `string` is destroyed at the end of the function, and therefore the pointer `str.c_str()` is a dangling pointer - pointing to a string that doesn't exist any more.

Solution is to just `return "john"`. Literals last forever.

```
    static const char *  func()
    {
        return "john";
    }
```

Or, better still, just return the `string`,

```
    static string  func()
    {
        std::string str = "john";
        return str;
    }
```

and use `abc::func().c_str()` at the call site.

(There may be other problems, but this is the most obvious to me)